# Rewrite "from" address to X-Gm-Original-To field

Tags: email, google-workspace

I own a domain name and use Google Workspace to manage the email for it (i.e. `example.com`). I have an email catch-all set up to forward all emails sent to the domain to a catch-all email address, and add the `X-Gm-Original-To` header so I know the original "To" address. I do this so that I can give out unique emails to any service that asks for an email address, for anonymization purposes. However, this anonymization disappears as soon as I reply to an email, as this exposes my primary email address in the "From" field.

Is there some way to get Google Workspace to rewrite outgoing email to change the "To" field to be whatever was in the "X-Gm-Original-To" field of the original message?

Alternately, is there some other mail service (free or paid) that can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish that by configuring the SMTP relay in Google Workspace and adding a "Dummy" account to an **external mail client, capable of authenticate to goggle workspace,** to send mail using *whatever@yordomain.any*

In the Admin console, go to Menu and then Apps > Google Workspace > Gmail >Routing.

Add an SMTP relay:

> in **Allow senders** select **Only addresses in my domains**
> (Sender doesn't have to be a Google Workspace user, but must be a user in one of your registered domains. This option is useful when you use third-party or custom applications to send messages.)

> in **Authentication** mark **Require SMTP Authentication**
> ( Enforces SMTP authentication to identify the sending domain (connection through TLS required). SMTP authentication verifies the connection by checking the user Google Workspace email address and password.)

> in **Encryption** mark **Require TLS encryption**

now you can send email with any name using the google SMTP (smtp-relay.gmail.com)

reference: https://support.google.com/a/answer/2956491?hl=en